# How to link OpenNI and NITE as external libraries

Tags: openi-tracker, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I'd like to link OpenNI and NITE to my own package as external libraries.**
How can I do it?

I'm using ROS groovy with Ubuntu 12.04.

In order to rosmake my package which uses OpenNI and NITE,
**I installed ros-groovy-openni-*.**
Next, I compiled and linked it with rosmake and rosmake was successed.

However, when running my package **I have a error with

xn::Context::InitFromXmlFile(const XnChar *strFileName, EnumerationErrors *pErrors=NULL) method.**
The error is "This operation is invalid".

Surprisingly, **the error didn't appear with ROS electric, Ubuntu 10.04, and ros-electric-openni-kinect.**
I think that it is a problem of the version of OpenNI and NITE.
So I'm trying to use OpenNI and NITE as external libraries instead of ros packages.

How can I link OpenNI and NITE to my package as external libraries?
Isn't it recommended ?
Any other people who have the same problem with ros-openni-* ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56391/how-to-link-openni-and-nite-as-external-libraries./) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing ros-groovy-openni*, you should first uninstall NITE 1.5.2, then install NITE 1.5.2.

As I said [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/54951/kinect-depth-registration-not-working-on-fuerte-and-groovy/#55036), it seems that uninstalling NITE first is needed... Otherwise some various problems appear.

Let me know,

Bests,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1